# what is the difference between below two ways of disabling the element in java script

Tags: javascript

I have to disable some elements in my Javas Script code , which one is better for disabling an element through Java Script :

```
 1.   document.getElementById("eleId").disabled = true;

 2.   document.getElementById("eleId").disabled = "disabled";
```

Please anyone describe these functions and what is the difference between these  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both cases are valid.

In case 1, you are setting the attribute 'disabled' to the boolean value 'true'.
In case 2, you are setting the attribute 'disabled' to the string value 'disabled'.

If you were going to set this value via HTML, normally you could get away with just having the bare attribute 'disabled' on the tag listed. But for XHTML/XML style compliance, you would use the well formed attribute disabled="disabled".

Basically, if the browser detects that the attribute 'disabled' is present, (I think) it will disable the element.

**EDIT**
Another SO user (RobG) pointed out that this sets the 'DOM property' of the element in question not the 'attribute'.

When dealing with the result from 'getElementById', you are dealing with a representation of the structure of the document.  When you make modifications you are settings properties on an 'object model'.  Having programmed in Java for so long, I typically interchange the term property & attribute.  In the case of saying "it sets the attribute", I was incorrect. Saying that I were to set the 'attribute' would mean that I would have modified the document (HTML) to change the value of "disabled" in the actual source. What this is actually doing is modifying the object tree setting the property of the representative object.

Comment: Niether line in the OP sets the disabled **attribute**, they set the **DOM property**.

Comment: @RobG very key distinction - I thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: So is there anywhere that says something about setting the **property** with certain values/types? Or is it the fact that non-empty strings are truthy and that triggers as `true`? I guess I'm just wondering what decides if the result should be true. So I'm thinking it's a truthy value, which is what a non-empty string is.

Comment: @Ian - you wold have to look at the DOM api. JavaScript unfortunately is VERY flexible as to what datatypes are coerced.

Comment: @DaveG Right, I just didn't know if you, for some reason, knew off-hand :) Hopefully, it's consistent between operations!

Answer (score 2):

In XHTML, attribute minimization is forbidden, and the disabled attribute must be defined as **disabled="disabled"**

In normal HTML, we can have like **disabled=true**

Answer (score 2):

Technically, if the attribute just HAS a disabled attribute, it should disable it. Although for XHTML, it must be disabled="disabled"

Answer (score 2):

The HTML [disabled attribtue](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#attr-fe-disabled) is boolean, its presence sets the related DOM property to `true` and is written in [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-disabled) and [HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#a-quick-introduction-to-html):

```
<... disabled ...>
```

In XML, attributes must have values, so for [XHTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#C_10) it's written:

```
<... disabled="disabled" ...>
```

however the actual value is irrelevant, it still works as a boolean attribute.

In the DOM, element properties usually reflect the related attribute value, but not always. There are also inconsistencies in how `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` work, so it's preferable in javascript to use DOM properties unless there is a good reason to use attributes instead (e.g. data- attributes).

To disable an element, the `disabled` DOM property should be set to boolean `true`, to "un–disable" the element, the property should be set to `false`. Assigning any string to the value will cause it to be set to `true` through type conversion.

Comment: Don't you mean "its presence sets the related DOM property to **`true`**" ? Or am I misreading that? I understand how they work, I just think the wording is messed up or I'm misreading.

Comment: Haha after I said that, I read in your comment on another answer the same text but with `true`. I knew you meant it :)

Answer (score 1):

people tend to get confused between the xhtml attribute value:

```
<input id="test" disabled="disabled"/>
```

and the javascript DOM api:

```
inputElement.disabled = true;
```

And set the javascript value to a string. It's not technically correct but it works fine.

Comment: It "works" only by accident. `disabled` is a boolean attribute, its presence sets the related DOM property to true, its absence sets it to false. Setting its value to **any** string will result in it being set to `true`. The use of `disabled="disabled"` was introduced to satisfy XML syntax, and almost no one serves XHTML on the web.